# WPF DataGrid Height is more than pages height

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, height, rendering

I have a page , here is the XAML . Think that the window has a TabControl , I create a tab -> frame -> page. The problem is that the two last DataGrids height is more that the page height! Any help appresiated! thanks.

```
<Page x:Class="pObjectDesigner"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:STUDIO_MANAGER_FRAMEWORK"
      mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="pObjectDesigner"
      d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="1050" MinWidth="500"
      Title="pObjectDesigner">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:ucMXMainToolBar Grid.Row="0" Allow_GoLeft="False" Allow_GoRight="False" x:Name="tlbToolBar" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" MinWidth="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TreeView x:Name="tlstObjects"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="grdPages"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                          ColumnWidth="Auto"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                          CanUserReorderColumns="True" />

                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" MinWidth="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" MinWidth="150"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="grdDataGrids"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                            ColumnWidth="Auto"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                            CanUserReorderColumns="True"/>

                    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    <DataGrid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="grdModules"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                            ColumnWidth="Auto"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                            CanUserReorderColumns="True"/>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Hi in DataGrid use AttachedProperty ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto

```
<DataGrid **ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"**
```

Similarlly you can set it for Horizontally .I hope this will help.

Comment: Yes I have read about it.. But the vertical scrollbar to the bottom-left datagrid is not Visible.. Do you know why??

Comment: It is not visible for bottom left DataGrid because DataGrid's Height is less than scroll area Height. If you want to always show that then set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible".

Comment: It will be visible if you will set the Property ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" . Or another way can be enclose your datagrid in ScrollViewer